# How to get gvfs CD mount point from Terminal?

Tags: bash, mount, cd, gvfs, mountpoint

I am writing a small bash script to automate transcoding CD's, which I would also like to make publicly available. For that I need to get the path where the CD is mounted by gvfs (on my machine `/run/user/$USER/gvfs/cdda:host=sr0`) into a variable. Is that possible at all, and if yes, how ?

Comment: I think this is not the best place to ask help for bash scripts.

Comment: @Keith5001 what would be a better place ?

Comment: stackoverflow.com

Comment: stackoverflow appears very active, so I would use a search engine to perhaps find a quieter place. eg search bash variable

Comment: @Keith5001 I think you misunderstood my question, my question isn't about how to get the output of a command into a bash variable, it's about how I can get the mount point of the CD drive.

Comment: I don't use gnome but there is a [gio](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio.html) command that might be what you seek. Eg `gio mount -l` can list current mounts.

Comment: @meuh apart from that it would be quite a piece of work to get the data `cdda://sr0/` out of `Drive(2): SD16G
  Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
  Volume(0): Intenso16GB
    Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
    Mount(0): Intenso16GB -> file:///media/user/Intenso16GB
      Type: GProxyMount (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
Mount(0): Audio-CD -> cdda://sr0/
  Type: GDaemonMount`, it's not he real path `/run/user/1000/gvfs/cdda:host=sr0`, but only the one gio uses internally.

Comment: @Programmer ok - good. Looks like I did.

Comment: @Keith5001 everyone makes mistakes, because no one is perfect (me and my communication included) ! ;)